# Dynamic Column Family in Datastax Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cql3, datastax-java-driver

As there is a way to create dynamic column family in Cassandra through CQL 3 i.e using a composite primary key with COMPACT STORAGE.

1. For inserting data in dynamic column family (wide rows), which will be efficient way, datastax java driver or Thrift API’s.
2. As I'm using Datastax, and Datastax highly suggest using non-compact tables for new developments, inspite non-compact table are less "compact" internally, then how should I need to create dynamic column family, with COMPACT STORAGE or without COMPACT STORAGE.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your other question. You should stay away from the Thrift API for new development. If you use the Trift API you will miss out on all the great features of CQL 3 including:

- Compound Keys
- Collections & other types
- Usability

Use the latest Datastax Java driver!

(2.1)
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/whatsNew2.html

Answer (score 2):

To do similar things to what you previously did with a "wide row" you will want to use a compound primary key that includes clustering columns.

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  sensor_id int,
  collected_at timestamp,
  volts float,
  PRIMARY KEY (sensor_id, collected_at)
);
```

See the following blog posts for more information on using wide partitions in CQL3 and how old thrift terminology relates to what you can do in CQL3:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/does-cql-support-dynamic-columns-wide-rows
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-for-cassandra-experts
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3